# Get all "user" key values from collection mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to get all "user" key values from collection in mongo?

`find` doesnt work for me, coz you have to specify the value of key here `find({ foo: 'bar' })` and I want to find not only item with `foo` equal to `bar` but every `foo` value from WHOLE collection.

`Example`: `({ foo: '123' }, { foo: '123456' })` and I want to get `123 and 123456`

P.S. Mongodb docs are probably worst docs ever created. Or the least intuitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method takes two parameters: `query` (you can pass an empty object to get all documents) and `projection` which specifies the fields you want to retrieve so in your case:

```
db.collection.find( {}, { foo: 1 })
```

Comment: There's also [`collection.distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) that does something similar, but will return an array rather than a cursor

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
db.mongo.find({"user":/.*./});
```

this way it searches any matching characters in the whole collection with key "user" in it